# Converting relative url path to absolute url for xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, django-views, xhtml2pdf

I am very inexperienced in this so I have problem understanding [documentation provided](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/xhtml2pdf/stable/xhtml2pdf.pdf) for `xhtml2pdf` since it is very vague in details. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

According to documentation to convert relative url path to absolute I need to use provided function:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    """
    Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
    resources
    """
    # use short variable names
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        return uri  # handle absolute uri (ie: http://some.tld/foo.png)

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise Exception(
                'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
            )
    return path
```

I added exact same function to my `views.py` and using  this function for generating pdf (also in `views.py`, almost directly taken form docs):

```
def PGP_result(request):

    data = request.session['form_data']

    lietuvosPgp = data['LtPGP']
    valstybe = data['pVal']
    kastai = data['iKastai']
    rezultatas = data['result']  
    today = timezone.now()

    params = {
            'LtPgp': lietuvosPgp,
            'Valstybe': valstybe,
            'Kastai': kastai,
            'Rezultatas': rezultatas,
            'today': today,
        }

    template_path = 'PGP_results_pdf.html'

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'

    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(params)

    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(
        html, dest=response, link_callback=link_callback
        )
    if pisaStatus.err:
        return HttpResponse('Ups kažkas nepavyko <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

Pdf is generated, but font file residing in `static/fonts` folder is not used. I cannot figure out how to correctly write relative url path so it would be converted to absolute one. I guess solution should be very simple, but my lack of experience prevents me from finding it (I tired various ways of writing it, but none of them worked)  .

My (current) template code (do not know how to fix `src: url(sUrl/fonts/Arial.ttf)` part):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
   <style type="text/css">
         @font-face {
            font-family: "Arial"; src: url(sUrl/fonts/Arial.ttf);
        }
        .container {
            font-family: "Arial"
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Skaičiuota - {{ today | date:"d/m/Y" }}</h3>
        </div>  
        <div class="list-group">
            <p>{{ LtPgp }}</p>
            <p>{{ Valstybe }}</p>
            <p>{{ Kastai }}</p>
            <p>{{ Rezultatas }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try passing sUrl to your template and parsing it by the templating engine `{{sUrl}}`??

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: in `def PGP_result(request)` add the `sURL` to  the params dictionary and in the html `src: url({{sUrl}}/fonts/Arial.ttf);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading bunch of more or less similar questions, I stumbled on comment recommending to run `py manage.py collectstatic` command first. After reading this and analyzing `link_callback function more I found solution:

In template should be:   `font-family: "Arial"; src: "static/fonts/Arial.ttf";`

In my conclusion `link_callback` function checks for the link first part and if it finds that link starts with `static` it replaces it with directory to `STATIC_ROOT` (absolute path). Since I was working on development server with `Debug=True` I did not needed to `collectstatic` for everything else, so while everything worked, `link_callback` function directed to non existing (yet) directory. After collecting all the statics and fixing source link I got it working.

P.S. I am not professional and have no programming background, so please fix my assumptions if they are wrong (I realy want to learn and know more). But even if assumptions are wrong code now works fine.